# php id of element td inside of td

Tags: javascript, php

i have that table, i would like to take ID's of the td's inside of all of the elements of td by php or JS.

Can you help me ?

```
<table id="czytelnicy">
    <tr>
        <td class="kolumna pogrubienie">I</td>
        <td class="kolumna pogrubienie" id="B_1_1">B_1_1</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_2">B_1_2</td> 
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_3">B_1_3</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_4">B_1_4</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_5">B_1_5</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_6">B_1_6</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_7">B_1_7</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_8">B_1_8</td>
        <td class="kolumna pogrubienie" id="B_1_9">B_1_9</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_10">B_1_10</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_11">B_1_11</td>
        <td class="kolumna pogrubienie" id="B_1_12">B_1_12</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_13">B_1_13</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try to solve the problem?

Comment: i'm beginner and don't know how to start , can you help me ?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to do. As it stands your question does not make your requirements clear. See [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

**USE JQUERY**

```
var index = 1;
$("table#czytelnicy tr td").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id', 'B_1_'+index+'');
   index++;
});
```

Comment: your answers are very helpful but now i want to put a ID inside a td as text

for example :

    <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_2">B_1_2</td>

Comment: You want to add an id="B_1_2">B_1_2" to all tds ?? Right??

Comment: are you creating this table dynamically? Then provide that code please. It ll help me to help you.

Comment: no no , i want to add id like that <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_3">B_1_3</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_4">B_1_4</td>
        <td class="kolumna" id="B_1_5">B_1_5</td>

Answer (score 0):

Using Plain JavaScript

```
var ids = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var id_arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    id_arr.push(ids[i].id);
}

console.log(id_arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["", "B_1_1", "B_1_2", "B_1_3", "B_1_4", "B_1_5", "B_1_6", "B_1_7", "B_1_8", "B_1_9", "B_1_10", "B_1_11", "B_1_12", "B_1_13"]
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht0uwnp9/)

Comment: @ johnroe good logic . This is totally new for me bcz i always work with class name . this really a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery. You can put every id in an array.

```
var idArray = [];

$("table#czytelnicy tr td").each(function(){

 idArray.push($(this).attr("id"));

});

return idArray
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnq2bzsh/)**

You can return it or do whatever you want. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.kolumna').each(function(){
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

//this give all id under that class